# "Making" a continuous function differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Assume $u:R^n_{++} \to R$ is a arbitrary continuous function. Does there exists some strictly increasing $h: R \to R$ such that $h \circ u$ is differentiable?
I don't think so, but I have not yet managed to find a counterexample. I am not even sure how to approach a "proof" of an counterexample, as you would have to show that for any strictly increasing h, the composition is not differentiable.

This is no exercise I was given, I am asking myself this question out of curiosity.

Comment: For $n=1$ this and related questions are studied in Chapter 9. *Transformations via Homeomorphisms* (pp. 85-99; also pp. 175-176) in [**Differentiation of Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821869906) by Andrew M. Bruckner (1994, 2nd edition). See also [*Differentiability through change of variables*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-061-02/S0002-9939-1976-0432831-2/S0002-9939-1976-0432831-2.pdf) by Bruckner/Goffman and google ["Differentiability through change of variables" + Bruckner](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22differentiability+through+change+of+variables%22&filter=0)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro What about transformations by continuous functions in general into differentiable functions ?

Comment: @Vivaan Daga: I only know about some of this literature (that I cited) and I've never really pursued it myself (and it has been a few years -- porobably over 10 years -- since I've done more than glance at it), so I don't have anything more specific to offer than to look through the literature that the references I gave lead you to.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Are there any examples of continuous functions that can not be transformed by a inner/outer non constant continuous function ?

Comment: @Vivaan Daga: I don't really know much about this and can't look into it now (very busy with contract work). However, I remember seeing a similar question recently on mathoverflow -- [Transforming a continuous function into a differentiable function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/371665/15780).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks ,Today  I asked it here as a real analysis question

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro In fact some trivial observation can be made for example the function can’t be both increasing and differentiable on any interval . Then a nowhere differentiable function will appear as a counter example , But still there exist nowhere monotonic differentiable function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g = (g_1, g_2): \mathbb [0,1] \to \mathbb [0,1]^2$ be continuous and surjective (a space-filling curve).  Suppose $h_1$ and $h_2$ are strictly increasing functions from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ such that $h_1 \circ g_1$ and $h_2 \circ g_2$ are differentiable.  Then $(h_1 \circ g_1, h_2 \circ g_2)$ is a differentiable space-filling curve.  But [that is impossible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists/201450).  We conclude that for at least one of $g_1$ and $g_2$, no such $h$ exists.